# Pyspark Array column to dataframe

Tags: arrays, pyspark

i need to transform an array column in pyspark dataframe to a dataframe itself.

Input:

| number | values | combination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | [e, f, g] | `[[e, f],[e,g],[f,g]...]` |
| b | [e, f, g ,h] | `[[e, f],[e,g],[f,g],[f,h]...]` |
| c | [b, c] | `[[b, c]]` |

i want to get in output only the column combination as:

| value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| e | f |
| e | g |
| f | g |
| e | f |
| e | g |
| f | g |
| f | h |
| b | c |

i want the extract line by line in the same dataframe without loop functions.

Comment: Explode combination and create 2 columns with combination [0] and combination [1] if size of all arrays in combination will remain 2 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say input dataframe is df.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.select(F.explode(df.combination).alias("values"))
df = df.select(df.values[0].alias('value1'), df.values[1].alias('value2'))
```

Comment: The explode part works perfectly but the next line return an erreur cannot resolve df.values[0] it neads leteral value not 0

Comment: It would have made more sense if you added the schema. That helps write accurate code snippets. @AliMtibaa Could you please add the schema as part of question so that it could be more intuitive for others?